# change font size in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-2.2-froyo

I have made a `ListView` in my android application.
But the problem is that the font size is larger then the requirements of application.
I have tried to solve this but I can't find any property or any other method of setting the font of `ListView`.

Does anybody have any idea how to change font size of list view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make custom layout of row then you are able to set font size of the list view according to your requirement here i am giving some link for creating custom layout for listview.

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1

i hope this is help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font size in your row layout, or manually with code in your list adapter's newView() and/or bindView() methods. Post your row layout and/or adapter code for more help.